# How do I put a bridge on top of a bonded interface?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, bridge, bonding

I'm setting up a Ubuntu Server 11.10 box with multiple Ethernet interfaces that are bonded for redundancy. I'm planning to use it as a KVM host, so I'll need a network bridge.

To accomplish this, I installed ifenslave and bridge-utils, then wrote my `/etc/network/interfaces` file. The relevant portion is as follows:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.1.254.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.1.254.0
    broadcast 10.1.254.255
    gateway 10.1.254.50
    dns-nameservers 10.1.254.252
    bridge_ports bond0
    bridge_stp off

iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-slaves eth0 eth3
    bond_mode balance-rr
    bond_miimon 100
```

Unfortunately, this isn't giving me connectivity. `ifup br0` gives me "`can't add bond0 to bridge br0: Invalid argument`", and `ifdown br0` gives me "`device bond0 is not a slave of br0`". If I modify my `interfaces` file to get rid of the bridge, I have full connectivity—but I'm going to need the bridge.

I think something in my `interfaces` file is wrong, but I don't know how to make it right. Does anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually find a satisfactory answer or get this working?  If so please provide your solution.  I'm wanting to do exactly the same thing but with DHCP

Comment: Sorry, the project ended up being abandoned for awhile. I'll look back into it.

Comment: The answer you're looking for, several years late, is you're missing an auto statement. Your file should look like auto bond0, the bond0 definition, auto br0, then the br0 definition.

Comment: @diablo-D3, auto doesnt help. I have the same problem.

Comment: @eos In the example op gave, there are also no matching lines to bring the bridge members up. This is also a common configuration error. Listing bond-slaves doesn't up them.

Comment: @eos did you install bridge-utils?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I configured a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system for bridging on top of bonded interfaces:

```
iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth5 inet manual

# eth0 & eth5 form bond0 for the x.y.z.0/25 subnet
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        bond_miimon 100
        bond_mode active-backup
        bond_downdelay 200
        bond_updelay 200
    address x.y.z.35
    netmask 255.255.255.128
    network x.y.z.0
    post-up ifenslave bond0 eth0 eth5
    pre-down ifenslave -d bond0 eth0 eth5

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports bond0
    address x.y.z.35
    netmask 255.255.255.128
    network x.y.z.0
    gateway x.y.z.126
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this lines to definition of br0 interface:

```
    pre-up ifup bond0
    post-down ifdown bond0
```